# Xcode running Redpark on iPhone

Tags: iphone, xcode, arduino

Alright, so I'm at wits' end.

I have an app that utilizes pushing and popping viewControllers. one of my viewControllers has the basic setup for reading input from the Arduino Uno (utilizing the Redpark cable).

When I pop that view controller off the app dies and I do not know what is causing it. I know it has to do with the Redpark coding because without it the app works fine.

When I insert the Redpark coding into the other viewControllers the app doesn't die but the text that I have to read the serial code disappears.

So what is causing it to crash? Or not show the data.

I think it has to do with [rscMgr open] command. Any input would be useful.

---

EDIT: let me also ask. Is there a way to run this process of reading the serial data in the background of my app? That might solve the problem.

Comment: Show the relevant code. Btw - is there any example code for using that cable? Hadn't heard of it before.

Comment: Most if not all the code is inside the Redpark Serial SDK all I have written is the same as Alasdair Allan's code here http://programmingiphonesensors.com/redpark/cable.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I believe I solved the problem, or just put a band-aid on it.

Throughout the book "iOS Sensor Apps with Arduino" by Alasdair Allen all the examples were created in the main viewController.

I was playing around with the examples plus extra view controllers. I came to the realization that the main viewController is ALWAYS RUNNING.

What I did to solve the problem was to create a global variable that held the inputs and then printed it to the pushed viewController.

I also used a timer to update the value in the pushed viewController.

So...

1. Create a variable that will hold the input. I did this in the AppDelegate class (I tend to put all global variables in the AppDelegate).

   ```
   @synthesize rxBuffed = _rxBuffed;
   ```
2. Run the Redpark Serial input on the main viewController using `rxBuffed` variable (could call it anything you want).

   ```
   for (int i = 0; i < numBytes; i++) {
   delegate.rxBuffed = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%c", delegate.rxBuffed, ((char *)rxBuffer)[i]];
   }
   ```
3. Create your timer in your viewController that you want the RX data. I update every 1/10th of a second.

   ```
   myTimer =[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:.1
   target:self selector:@selector(updateValues)
   userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
   ```
4. Import that variable in the updateValues.

   ```
   -(void)updateValues{
   AppDelegate *delegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
   yourVariable = delegate.rxBuffed;
   }
   ```